# How can I save the state of the power button when I am changing beetwen tabs in SwifUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I´m making a IOS app where I have a tabview. that tabview contains 3 different views, in one of these, i have a power button which has a growing animation, but when the view is changed, the power button back to off state. I´ll show you my code:

```
struct MainTabView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = MainTabViewModel()
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(viewModel.tabTitle).font(.largeTitle).bold().padding()
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
            TabView(selection: $viewModel.selectedIndex) {
                // view where is the button which activates the service
                GPSButtonView()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            viewModel.selectedIndex = 0
                        }
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "playpause")
                        }
                        .tag(0)
                //view where is the map view
                Text("Map")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            viewModel.selectedIndex = 1
                        }
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "map")
                        }
                        .tag(1)
                SettingsView()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            viewModel.selectedIndex = 2
                        }
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "gear.circle")
                        }
                        .tag(2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct GPSButtonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = GPSButtonViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(
                    action: {
                        //button tapped
                        viewModel.gpsState.toggle()
                        viewModel.show.toggle()

                    }
            ) {
                Image(systemName: "power.circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(viewModel.gpsState ? .green : .red)
                        .scaleEffect(viewModel.show ? 2 : 1)
                        .animation(
                                Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5),
                                value: viewModel.show
                        )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class GPSButtonViewModel: ObservableObject {
    //properties
    @Published var gpsState = false
    @Published var show = false
}
```

I´ll show you too a gif of the problem:
[problem gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzj6C.gif)

Comment: You could look into `@SceneStorage`. But, I'm imagining that you actually want the button to be connected to some sort of important state in your app long term that actually affects things, so you may want to make an architectural decision about how you want to store/persist state in general.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using objects in SwiftUI like this, it's best to use structs, e.g.

```
struct GPSButtonConfig {
    var gpsState = false
    var show = false
}
```

Then do

```
@State var config = GPSButtonConfig()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could conserve the state of the button by moving the ButtonViewModel up in the hierarchy.

Add this to your `MainTabView`:

```
@StateObject var buttonViewModel = GPSButtonViewModel()
```

and when you call your view:

```
GPSButtonView(viewModel: buttonViewModel)
    .onTapGesture {
        viewModel.selectedIndex = 0
    }
    .tabItem {
        Image(systemName: "playpause")
    }
    .tag(0)
```

### and **important**

remove the initializer from your buttonview:

```
struct GPSButtonView: View {
        @ObservedObject var viewModel: GPSButtonViewModel
```

Comment: It's true @StateObject will fix the bug but they shouldn't be using an object in the first place!

Comment: @malhal I agree. For this purpose a struct at `MainTabView` level would be best. But as they named it `GPSButtonViewModel` i assumed there is more here than just state, e.g. functionality that is not shown.